# Resize background with Gimp

Tags: gimp, resize, background

sorry for my English..

I have this image,

[image]

it is 468px x 531px and I to want to change to 792px x 1040.

I search on internet how does it, on **image** + **Canvas size**, my problem is when to change the size, change the image size, when I'll only to change the **background** size,  not the image...

Can please someone help me and with easy words say how can do it? Thanks!

I want to have like this image

[image: image what I to want]

This image has 792px x 1040px.

The steps I to do for change the size from the image,

1)With gimp open the image,

[image: first step]

2) On **File** + **New** open a new window with 792px x 1040.

3)With **Rectangle select tool** select the image and copy it, and bring to the new Window

[image: image on the new window]

how to see, now the image from the product is smaller...

My question how can prevent this problem and become on this window the product image identical as the firs image ?

Comment: You mean you want [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDpk5.jpg)? Background resized, picture same size.. or resize the entire image without stretching, or...?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, not ..I update my question..

Comment: Still hard to tell what you mean. that looks like you want "a bit of each" some enlargement, some padding… but it's still not really clear to me.

Comment: yes, I'll the image padding to the margin of the ram, but when to try it, it (the product)to become small...

Comment: I'll as you image, Background resized, and the image from the product also...

Comment: resize canvas and resize layer?

Comment: Maybe...because I'm very new with image working I don' t know how to do it..on internet a to show videos how to does it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIFB_cix4Cw but not working foe me..

Comment: If you want everything to be bigger, use Image>Scale image (but the backpack will be slightly blurry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convenient way would be to:

1. Select the canvas color using the Gimp "Eyedropper" tool from the background color select box.

   [image]
2. Choose *Image > Canvas size...* for this dialog:

   [image]

In this box enter the desired "Canvas Size", choose "Center" for centering the original content, "resize al layers" if applicable, and fill with "Background Color" as defined above for the following result:

[image]

Comment: Very thanks for your bother, ! all working gut that problem is that product (yellow backpack) to come to small https://i.imgur.com/64eoSkA.jpg it is possible with your method the product big to do?

Comment: Not in one go I am afraid, but you can always scale the original image prior to increasing the canvas size (*Image > Scale Image*).

Comment: Very Thanks! Now I have how I like.. https://i.imgur.com/oxmLTR6.png I wish you a nice day!

Comment: @jdgs56z phantastic - nice job!